# Prove or disprove $\sqrt{(x_1)^2+ \cdots +(x_n)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x_1)^2}+ \cdots + \sqrt{(x_n)^2}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Let $\vec{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is it true that $\sqrt{(x_1)^2+ \cdots +(x_n)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x_1)^2}+ \cdots + \sqrt{(x_n)^2}$?

It looks very obvious but I can't find a way to prove it. I tried induction but failed.

Comment: Induction means you only need to prove it for $n=2$.  Note that$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$. Better to use suffixes to avoid all those parantheses.

Comment: Hint: is it true that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \le |a| +|b|$?

Comment: Does $x^i$ mean $x$ to the power $i$ in your question?

Comment: $x^i$ means the i-th coordinate of the vector $\vec{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Induction could work, sure.

Note that $(|x| + |y|)^2 = |x|^2 + |y|^2 + 2|x||y| \ge |x|^2 +|y|^2$, so $\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} \le |x| + |y|$.

Now, as Thomas Andrew's comment says, you're done.

Comment: And, of course, instead of using induction you could write the same thing for any $n\ge 2$.

Comment: is there other ways to prove it without using induction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. In fact $\sqrt{(x^1)^2} = |x^1|$ and the same to the others, you can take square both sides. Then it is equivalent to prove

$(x^1)^2+ \cdots +(x^n)^2 \leq (|x^1|+|x^2|+\cdots+|x^n|)^2$

Which is obvious by expansion formula.

Answer (score 0):

this graph shows that $e^{\frac12\ln(x)} \leq x $ $ \forall x \in ]0,+\infty[$
(if $x=0$ the inequality holds because $0 = 0$)

just take $x = |x^1|+|x^2|+\dots|x^n|$

so $e^{\frac12\ln(|x^1|+|x^2|+\dots|x^n|)} \leq |x^1|+|x^2|+\dots|x^n|$ is equivalent to the inequality you're trying to prove

[image]

Comment: Graph isn't a proof, though. Needs some justification.

Comment: you could study the function if you want a more rigorous proof